# Svelte transition send/receive works only for last element of list

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm trying to understand why proper transition (without default fallback works) only when I move the last element of the initial list (or DOM). So given list of 3 objects:

```
[{"id": 22, "name": f"{message}", 'favourite': 'false'},
{"id": 33, "name": "33333", 'favourite': 'false'},
{"id": 44, "name": "444444", 'favourite': 'false'}]
```

Regardless whether I move it as first or last, only id:44 element of the initial list is animated.

```
<script>
import {Button, Card, CardBody, CardHeader, CardSubtitle, CardText, CardTitle, Col, Row} from "sveltestrap";
import { send, receive } from './transition.js';
import {hotelList} from './stores.js'

$: hotels = $hotelList

function addFavourite (hotelId) {
    // Find the hotel in the list by id
    const hotelIndex = $hotelList.findIndex(hotel => hotel.id === hotelId);
        console.log(hotelIndex)

    // If the hotel is found, add the 'favourite' property
    if (hotelIndex !== -1) {
        hotels[hotelIndex]['favourite'] = 'true'
        hotelList.set(hotels)
        }}
</script>
<div>
{#if hotels && hotels.length > 0}
<h3>Hotels</h3>
<Row>
{#each hotels.filter((hotel) => hotel.favourite !== 'true') as hotel}
        <div in:receive={{ key: hotel.id }} out:send={{ key: hotel.id }}>
        <Col xs="3">
        <Card class="mb-3">
            <CardHeader>
                <CardTitle>{hotel.name}
                    <i class='bi bi-bag-plus-fill favourite' on:click={() => addFavourite(hotel.id)}></i>
                </CardTitle>
            </CardHeader>
        </Card>
    </Col>
    </div>
{/each}
</Row>
{/if}
</div>

<div>
{#if hotels && hotels.length > 0}
<h3>Favourites</h3>
<Row>
{#each hotels.filter((hotel) => hotel.favourite === 'true') as hotel}
        <div in:receive={{ key: hotel.id }} out:send={{ key: hotel.id }}>
        <Col xs="3">
        <Card class="mb-3">
            <CardHeader>
                <CardTitle>{hotel.name}
                    <i class='bi bi-bag-plus-fill favourite' on:click={() => addFavourite(hotel.id)}></i>
                </CardTitle>
            </CardHeader>
        </Card>
    </Col>
    </div>
{/each}
</Row>
{/if}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move and insert items, you generally need an `#each` key, so Svelte can identify the affected items properly.

If no key is set, Svelte will assume that elements are added to or removed from the end of the array.

Keys need to uniquely identify items, in this case you probably want something like:

```html
{#each hotels.filter(...) as hotel (hotel.id)}
```

See [`#each` docs](https://svelte.dev/docs/logic-blocks#each) for details.